# Particles render in front of other objects

Tags: rendering, particles, blender-internal-render-engine

**Situation**: I wanted to render a scene which is made up of a few flowers model in the foreground, and in the background, I have a grass particle system.

**Problem**: Whenever I tried to render, there seems to be a bug which looks like the image below. It's as if a part of the grass is displayed over the flowers, which should've been in the background. How do I fix this?

After trying over, I found that one solution is to turn off 'strand render' under render settings on the particle system of the grass. That way, I wouldn't see those overlaying grass effect. However, when I turn it off, I would have a different result for my grass and it doesn't look good at all.
Here is my Blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30319

Well, my blend file is too big to be uploaded so I deleted some settings and objects in order to have as minimum size as possible. I used just a plane on the blend file above. but as you can see the problem still applies. When we render, there are a few traces of grass over the plane.

[image]

Comment: Use multiple render layers, and overlay them in the compositor. Also, Cycles is better for most stuff, except for NPR, so use Cycles.

Comment: Try increasing the end clipping distance in the camera past the plane with grass

Comment: Thankyou! Turns out changing the end clipping distance really solved it all!

Comment: @Steven.Cooler Could you please add the solution as an answer .

Comment: @cegaton Maybe you should answer, if you want..

Comment: @gandalf3 this would be of course better when cegaton gets the rep for this.

Comment: @gandalf3 I know this works but I wouldn't be able to elaborate on why...

Answer (score 4):

The hint from cegaton's comment solved the issue. I had only to increase the end clipping distance in the camera behind the plane with grass.